# AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'binary_type'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd

df = web.DataReader('RTSI', 'moex', start='2015-01-01', end='2019-12-30')
df
```

---

It results with the following error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df = web.DataReader('RTSI', 'moex', start='2015-01-01', end='2019-12-30')
>         2 #Show teh data
>         3 df
>
> 2 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/moex.py in
>   _get_metadata(self)
>       103                 raise IOError("{} request returned no data; check URL for invalid "
>       104                               "inputs: {}".format(service, self.__url_metadata))
>   --> 105             if isinstance(text, pd.compat.binary_type):
>       106                 text = text.decode('windows-1251')
>       107
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'binary_type'

Comment: What are the versions of the `pandas` and the `pandas_datareader` packages?
I have successfully ran the code.

Answer (score 0):

Given version of `pandas_datareader` was probably based on an earlier version of `pandas` when `pd.compat.binary_type` was filled. I solved the same problem by putting a one-liner before the data query:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd

pd.compat.binary_type = bytes

df = web.DataReader('RTSI', 'moex', ...)
df
```